# Angular 5 router outlet for child doesn't work

Tags: angular, routes, outlet

I am working on angular project, but I can't add "outlet" for a child route.
These are the routing parameters which are already called by the main module but I don't know why it doesn't work.

this is the main route

```
const routes: Routes = [
            {path: '', component: ContainerComponent},
            {path: 'search', component: SearchComponent},
            {path: 'sign-in',  loadChildren: './../signIn_Module/sign-in.module#SignInModule'},
            {path: 'sign-up', loadChildren: './../signUp_Module/sign-up.module#SignUpModule'},
            {path: 'home', loadChildren: './../home_Module/home.module#HomeModule'},
            {path: 'user', loadChildren: './../profile_Module/profile.module#ProfileModule'},
            {path: 'training', loadChildren: './../Training_Module/training.module#TrainingModule'},

            {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

this is the route which contains the problem

```
const trainingRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: TrainingComponent, children: [
     {path: 'title', component: TitleComponent, outlet: 'training_content'},
     {path: 'image', component: ImageComponent, outlet: 'training_content'},
     {path: 'description', component: DescriptionComponent, outlet: 'training_content'},
     {path: 'file', component: FileComponent, outlet: 'training_content'},
     {path: 'requirement', component: RequirementComponent, outlet: 'training_content'},
     {path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent, outlet: 'training_content'},
     {path: '**', redirectTo: 'title', pathMatch: 'full'}
  ]},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

Comment: What is not working, is the router link changing the path and not displaying content?

Comment: If possible replicate your issue on stackblitz

Comment: @Vivek when i want to go for example to /training/image it take me bake to /training

Comment: are you using it like this `RouterModule.forChild(parentModuleRoutes)`

Comment: so how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the first routing to fullpath

```
 {path: '', component: ContainerComponent},
```

to

```
 {path: '', component: ContainerComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```